# Message = "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." while sending notification to multiple devices

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, json, firebase

I have integrated firebase to send notification in my .NET application. In my application I am using **registration_ids** to  send notifications to multiple ID's and data is in JSON  format.
Here is my code

```
var webAddr = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "key=*******);
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;

string[] deviceIds = new string[] { "fm1MWzVyRxA:APA91bFKTAUwCVJCYT1GbMB6dTK5DPAApuxY01yPJtPpnGwtHkavSWFm5SRVMQtCWrtfTH3pN_8mxEFU-o0TwgFtN-2JtLxn4DkMVYw80OnfWqhV93z72PR9rZgdGI77CulMoCWtUO1_", "fy79LobUOxg:APA91bGG7DUMhfO2gRPjINMS1Vfh_RdZdUJH5r_GKipHB50e6sc5J2pexo9-Xd1cfpJyAqAZjJ6ylMhKpHm75jPXyEtB2bH0Onqr6Ln0baIXxuWNxmHl7zXWNmWeoI9q-GP_FnlcI6AH" };

var datat = new
{
    registration_ids = deviceIds,
    notification = new
    {
        body = "Osama",
        title = "AlBaami",
        sound = "Enabled"
    }
};
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var json = serializer.Serialize(datat);
```

here is my json data

```
{"registration_ids":["fm1MWzVyRxA:APA91bFKTAUwCVJCYT1GbMB6dTK5DPAApuxY01yPJtPpnGwtHkavSWFm5SRVMQtCWrtfTH3pN_8mxEFU-o0TwgFtN-2JtLxn4DkMVYw80OnfWqhV93z72PR9rZgdGI77CulMoCWtUO1_","fy79LobUOxg:APA91bGG7DUMhfO2gRPjINMS1Vfh_RdZdUJH5r_GKipHB50e6sc5J2pexo9-Xd1cfpJyAqAZjJ6ylMhKpHm75jPXyEtB2bH0Onqr6Ln0baIXxuWNxmHl7zXWNmWeoI9q-GP_FnlcI6AH"],"notification":{"body":"Osama","title":"AlBaami","sound":"Enabled"}}
```

while in this line

```
 var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

where I am getting responce showing me error Message = **"`The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."`**
i had vaidated the json format also and it is valid so what should be the possible solution for the problem

Answer (score -1):

In my application I can send successfully notifications using **to** instead of **registration_ids**.
Furthermore, I use an additional header:

```
Sender: id={server_id}
//Where server_id is the server_id that can be found in Firebase -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Cloud Messaging
```

Comment: i mentioned in my question that i am sending it on muiltiple devices

Comment: Then you should create a device_group that contains the device ids you want to contact and then use the device_group id to send the notification. Please refer to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)